# Count occurrences of a factor in a column in one dataframe and output in another

Tags: r, dataframe, counting

I am new here and I definitely need your help : I want to count the number of occurrences of a factor (1 column, 2 levels) and the number of lines (or observations) for 4 categories in a dataframe and display the output in another summarizing dataframe.

I explain : I did an experiment where I measured the shell temperature of animals (limpets) I put on a fake mussel bed. I want to know how many of my animals are exposed or sheltered (position) for each time point, infestation level and replicates.

Here is what my first dataframe (infauna) looks like :

```
> dput(infauna)
structure(list(date = c("14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", 
"14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021", "14/04/2021"), day.type = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "sunny", class = "factor"), 
    time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("0", 
    "30", "60", "90"), class = "factor"), real.time = c("10:55", 
    "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", 
    "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", 
    "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", 
    "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", 
    "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", 
    "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "10:55", "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", 
    "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", 
    "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", 
    "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", 
    "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", "11:25", "11:55", "11:55", "11:55", 
    "11:55", "11:55", "11:55", "11:55", "11:55", "11:55", "11:55", 
    "11:55", "11:55", "11:55", "11:55", "11:55", "11:55", "11:55", 
    "11:55", "11:55", "11:55", "11:55", "12:25", "12:25", "12:25", 
    "12:25", "12:25", "12:25", "12:25", "12:25", "12:25", "12:25", 
    "12:25", "12:25", "12:25", "12:25", "12:25", "12:25", "12:25", 
    "12:25", "12:25", "12:25", "12:25", "12:25", "12:25"), infauna = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Scutellastra granularis", class = "factor"), 
    infestation = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("clean", 
    "infested"), class = "factor"), replicate = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    specimen = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L), shell.temp = c(23.5, 
    24.1, 24, 23.8, 23.9, 23.1, 22.7, 23.3, 24.3, 24.4, 23.6, 
    24.2, 23.2, 25, 26.5, 25, 25.4, 24.3, 25.9, 22.6, 25, 26.4, 
    25, 24.8, 25.7, 24.1, 24.6, 24.9, 24, 25, 23.4, 24.2, 24.5, 
    25.3, 26.2, 26.6, 25.8, 25.7, 25.8, 25.3, 32.3, 30.2, 31.4, 
    32.4, 29.8, 33.8, 36, 36.4, 35.2, 37.5, 33.9, 30.4, 29.7, 
    35.8, 32.9, 28.2, 27.7, 35.3, 36.1, 35.8, 34.8, 33.2, 32.7, 
    28.1, 31.4, 31, 37, 30.6, 36.3, 37.1, 35.7, 34.3, 38.6, 36.4, 
    38, 33, 29.7, 32.2, 36.2, 38.3, 39, 37.1, 33.7, 35.3, 36.5, 
    30.1, 38.2, 36.2, 33.7, 36.2, 37.6, 38.6, 39.4, 34.2, 42.4, 
    39, 40.2, 34.6, 33, 32.7, 32.5, 42, 40.8, 38.1, 35.1, 38.8, 
    31.5, 37.3, 37.4, 36.1, 37.5, 40.1), position = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("exposed", "sheltered"
    ), class = "factor"), no.software = c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", 
    "M5", "M6", "M7", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M1", 
    "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", 
    "M5", "M6", "M7", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M1", 
    "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", 
    "M5", "M6", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M1", "M2", "M3", 
    "M4", "M5", "M6", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M1", "M2", "M3", 
    "M4", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M1", "M2", 
    "M3", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M1", "M2", 
    "M3", "M4", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", 
    "M1", "M2", "M3", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M1", "M2", "M3", 
    "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M1", "M2", "M3")), row.names = c(NA, 
-112L), class = "data.frame")
```

**This is an ongoing scientific research, so please don't share this dataset too widely :)**

I started to create a dataframe to summarize mean shell temperature, its standard deviation and the number of animals for each time point, infestation level, replicate and position with the following code (thanks to the comments) :

```
library(dplyr)
infauna.mean <- infauna %>%
  group_by(time, infestation, replicate, position, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  summarise(shell.mean = mean(shell.temp, na.rm=TRUE), 
            shell.sd = sd(shell.temp, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Which gives me the following output in the new dataframe (infauna.mean) :

```
> dput(infauna.mean)
structure(list(time = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L), infestation = c("clean", 
"clean", "clean", "clean", "clean", "infested", "infested", "infested", 
"infested", "infested", "infested", "clean", "clean", "clean", 
"clean", "clean", "infested", "infested", "infested", "infested", 
"infested", "infested", "clean", "clean", "clean", "clean", "clean", 
"infested", "infested", "infested", "infested", "infested", "infested", 
"clean", "clean", "clean", "clean", "infested", "infested", "infested", 
"infested", "infested", "infested"), replicate = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), position = c("exposed", "exposed", 
"sheltered", "exposed", "sheltered", "exposed", "sheltered", 
"exposed", "sheltered", "exposed", "sheltered", "exposed", "sheltered", 
"exposed", "exposed", "sheltered", "exposed", "sheltered", "exposed", 
"sheltered", "exposed", "sheltered", "exposed", "sheltered", 
"exposed", "exposed", "sheltered", "exposed", "sheltered", "exposed", 
"sheltered", "exposed", "sheltered", "exposed", "exposed", "exposed", 
"sheltered", "exposed", "sheltered", "exposed", "sheltered", 
"exposed", "sheltered"), shell.mean = c(23.8333333333333, 25.38, 
24.35, 25.9, 25.3, 23.7333333333333, 22.7, 25.35, 22.6, 24.36, 
24.2, 36.275, 33.9, 35.5, 37, 30.8, 31.85, 31.55, 34.35, 29, 
32.4333333333333, 28.1, 38.3, 36.4, 38.1333333333333, 37.2, 33.7, 
36.7, 35, 34.6, 30.95, 35.9, 31.9, 40.5333333333333, 40.3, 38.8, 
36.1, 37.95, 34.2, 34.6, 32.7333333333333, 37.8333333333333, 
33.3), shell.sd = c(0.53166405433005, 0.664830805543786, 0.353553390593274, 
0.447213595499958, NA, 0.372379734500505, NA, 0.771362431027075, 
NA, 0.66558245169175, NA, 0.956991814663705, NA, 0.57154760664941, 
NA, 0.282842712474618, 0.636396103067892, 1.88591268797542, 2.05060966544099, 
1.26227308191743, 0.929157324317759, NA, 0.42426406871193, NA, 
0.960902353693304, 1.4142135623731, NA, 0.565685424949241, 0.989949493661171, 
2.26274169979695, 1.76776695296637, 0.848528137423859, 2.54558441227157, 
1.72433562085034, 1.99749843554382, 1.83847763108502, NA, 1.37961347243832, 
NA, NA, 0.251661147842358, 0.838649708360608, 2.54558441227157
)), row.names = c(NA, -43L), groups = structure(list(time = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L), infestation = c("clean", 
"clean", "clean", "infested", "infested", "infested", "clean", 
"clean", "clean", "infested", "infested", "infested", "clean", 
"clean", "clean", "infested", "infested", "infested", "clean", 
"clean", "clean", "infested", "infested", "infested"), replicate = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2:3, 
    4:5, 6:7, 8:9, 10:11, 12:13, 14L, 15:16, 17:18, 19:20, 21:22, 
    23:24, 25L, 26:27, 28:29, 30:31, 32:33, 34L, 35L, 36:37, 
    38:39, 40:41, 42:43), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**I want to add two more columns to this dataframe with the following information** :

- **nb.position** : number of animals exposed or sheltered for each groups - translate in the **number of occurrence of "exposed" or "sheltered" in the column "position" for a given group** (e.g. t=0, infestation=clean, replicate=1, position=exposed, nb.position = 6)
- **nb.visible** : total number of animals visible for each group - translate in the **number of lines (observations) for a given group** (e.g. t=0, infestation=clean, replicate=1, position=exposed/sheltered, nb.visible = 6)

I tried several codes scavenged here and there, but without success. Here is a dummie version of the expected output I did by hand on Excel :

```
> dput(infauna.mean)
structure(list(time = c(0L, 30L, 60L, 90L, 0L, 30L, 60L, 90L, 
0L, 30L, 60L, 90L, 0L, 30L, 60L, 90L, 0L, 30L, 60L, 90L, 0L, 
30L, 60L, 90L), infestation = c("clean", "clean", "clean", "clean", 
"infested", "infested", "infested", "infested", "clean", "clean", 
"clean", "clean", "infested", "infested", "infested", "infested", 
"clean", "clean", "clean", "clean", "infested", "infested", "infested", 
"infested"), replicate = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    position = c("exposed", "exposed", "exposed", "exposed", 
    "exposed", "exposed", "exposed", "exposed", "exposed", "exposed", 
    "exposed", "exposed", "exposed", "exposed", "exposed", "exposed", 
    "exposed", "exposed", "exposed", "exposed", "exposed", "exposed", 
    "exposed", "exposed"), shell.mean = c(23.8333, 36.275, 38.3, 
    40.5333, 23.7333, 31.85, 36.7, 37.95, 25.38, 35.5, 38.1333, 
    40.3, 25.35, 34.35, 34.6, 34.6, 25.9, 37, 37.2, 38.8, 24.36, 
    32.4333, 35.9, 37.8333), shell.sd = c("0,5317", "0,9570", 
    "0,4243", "1,7243", "0,3724", "0,6364", "0,5657", "1,3796", 
    "0,6648", "0,5715", "0,9609", "1,9975", "0,7714", "2,0506", 
    "2,2627", "na", "0,4472", "na", "1,4142", "1,8385", "0,6656", 
    "0,9292", "0,8485", "0,8386"), nb.position = c(6L, 4L, 2L, 
    3L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L), x.position = c(0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 
    0.38, 0.75, 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.63, 0.5, 0.38, 0.38, 0.75, 
    0.25, 0.25, 0.13, 0.75, 0.13, 0.25, 0.25, 0.63, 0.38, 0.25, 
    0.38), nb.visible = c(6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L
    ), x.visible = c(0.75, 0.63, 0.38, 0.38, 0.88, 0.75, 0.5, 
    0.63, 0.88, 0.5, 0.38, 0.38, 0.88, 0.75, 0.5, 0.5, 0.88, 
    0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.75, 0.5, 0.5, 0.63)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

The columns "x.position" and "x.visible" are just percentages I did for graphic purposes.

Please note that I am actually a phD student and that I unfortunately don't have support on R. My supervisors and colleagues use Excel and Statistica, but I have 8 more datasets like this one and I don't want to do all the counts by hand (I  don't want to stay a caveman T.T).

Don't hesitate if you need more details and thank you so much for your time ! <3
Any help from the community will be acknowledged in my thesis and in my future published papers as well ;)

Comment: Please share your data by writing `dput(infauna)` and including the result in a code block. Also, it will help you get good answers if you more succinctly state what output you want to have.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use

```
library(dplyr)
result <- infauna %>%
            group_by(across(c(time:position, -shell.temp, -specimen)))%>%
            summarise(across(shell.temp, list(mean = ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE),
                        sd = ~ sd(., na.rm = TRUE))), .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: Your code gave me the following error message :

`Error: Problem with 'summarise()' input '..1'.
x Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column 'shell.temp' doesn't exist.
i Input '..1' is '(function (.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL) ...'.
i The error occurred in group 1: time = 0, real.time = "10:55", infauna = "Scutellastra granularis", infestation = "clean", replicate = 1, specimen = 1, shell.temp = 23.3, position = "exposed".`

@Ronak Shah's code just in the comment below works very well though !

Comment: @AlexiaDIEVART I assume that you have `shell.temp` column in the data.  May be you have an older version of `dplyr`. Can you check `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: I checked the `dput` of `infauna.mean`.  which doesn't have the 'shell.temp'.  As the `infauna` dput is not showed, not clear though

Comment: I added the dput for `infauna` after posting the question indeed, sorry ! `infauna.mean` doesn't contain a column `shell.temp` (referring to single observations), as the point of the manipulation is to get a column `shell.mean` and `shell.sd` for each category in this dataframe. My `dplyr` version is 1.0.5, is it old ?  I feel like the issues in your code might be the use of the function `across()`, with the following `list()`, but I am no coding expert. What do you think ?

Comment: @AlexiaDIEVART the real issue is that `time:position` also includes the 'shell.temp' in the range.  We have to remove those with `-shell.temp`.  Please see the update.

Comment: Moreover, `time: position` also includes the `specimen` (which is the individual observation), that's why it doesn't `group_by` properly. So, we have to remove both `-shell.temp, -specimen` for the code to work ! Could you please modify your code above ? However, the resulting dataframe still doesn't include null values. Could we add a `. drop = FALSE` somewhere to obtain this dataframe with null values as well ? Thank for this chat !

Comment: @AlexiaDIEVART I updatd the post.  Did you meant `.groups = 'drop'` in `summarise`.  The last part of your question is not clear to me

Answer (score 0):

For such calculations I would suggest to use `dplyr` as it is very convenient to perform multiple calculations. If your columns are factors use `.drop = FALSE` to kepp all the values.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- infauna %>%
  group_by(time, infestation, replicate, position, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  summarise(shell.mean = mean(shell.temp, na.rm=TRUE), 
            shell.sd = sd(shell.temp, na.rm=TRUE))
```